# Sitecore Media Library Error

Tags: sitecore, media

When I click "Browse" on an Image field in a content item, I get the following error message (object reference not set to an instance of an object):

```
[NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.]
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser.MediaBrowserForm.UpdateSelection(Item item) +754
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser.MediaBrowserForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +254

[TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +1255
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +91
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +332
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyn
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you turn on raw values in Sitecore and paste the contents of the image field into the question?

Comment: I turned on raw values, but there's nothing in that image field.

Comment: Ok, what version of Sitecore?

Comment: Sitecore 6.6, updated from 6.3.

Comment: It looks like the root media library root item cannot be found. Do you have the media library in place at /sitecore/media library? Also does the current logged in user have permissions to access the media library?

Comment: Also it could be some files missing in the sitecore/shell/applications/media directory

Comment: Do you mean in the Master DB? Yes, the /sitecore/media library item is there. I can open the tree under it without problems. The folder media directory doesn't exist in sitecore/shell/applications. There's a folder called media there with lots of subfolders in it. But that was also the case with the 6.3 system before the update to 6.6. And it was working. Am I missing that directory now?

Answer (score 1):

Found what was causing the problem. After removing the file MediaBrowser.xml in sitecore/shell/override that error message was gone. It seems there was something wrong in that overriding MediaBrowser.xml.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, two things could be wrong if you see that message.

1. As @SpaceJump mentioned, maybe the MediaBrowser.xml is not in the sitecore/shell/override.
2. MediaBrowser.xml file has an error or something is not there. In my case was that a button hadn't the ID attribute.

Ex:
Before (not working)

`<Button Header="Upload" Click="UploadImage"/>`

After (working)

`<Button ID="UploadButton" Header="Upload" Click="UploadImage"/>`